# PHP - Regex replace everything not letter or space and everything after it

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to write a regex that replaces everything after something that's not a space or a letter in PHP.

I currently have the following

```
$_product[self::NAME] = preg_replace('^[a-z .*$]+$/i', '', $_product[self::NAME]);
```

It replaces the string with a blank string.

Here are some examples of what I'm replacing

```
Milk - 50 Gallons
```

should return

```
Milk
```

This string

```
chocolate milk - 50 gallons
```

should return

```
chocolate milk
```

It should do the same even if the hyphens are not there, meaning

```
Milk 50 gallons
```

should return

```
Milk
```

What is wrong in my regex?

Comment: it shouldn't replace anything. your pattern is missing the opening `/`, so it's a syntax error. and in a character class (`[]`), `.`, `*`, and `$` are NOT wildcards and have no special meaning.

Comment: First, you've forgotten the delimiter, then give some sample input strings and expected result.

Comment: That regular expression wouldn't even parse. You also forgot to include the input you used that provided the unexpected result.

Comment: And `^` is not only `not`, it's also beginning of line.

Comment: `'/[^a-z\s].+$/i'`

Comment: I'd go for `'/[^a-z ].*$/i'`

Comment: Replace `(?![a-z ]).*` by everything you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *It replaces the string with a blank string* proves you made a typo when posting the question, and you actually have `'/^[a-z .*$]+$/i'` regex.

That also means that your regex matches any string that contains one or more chars from the `[a-z .*$]` set (ASCII letters, space, dot, `*` or `$` symbols).

If you need a *regex that replaces everything after something that's not a space or a letter*, you need

```
preg_replace('/\s*[^a-z\s].*$/i', '', $_product[self::NAME]);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uQ6gD3/1)

**Details**:

- `\s*`  - zero or more whitespaces
- `[^a-z\s]` - any char other than ASCII letter or whitespace
- `.*` - any zero or more characters other than newline (add `/s` modifier to also match newlines)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: _It replaces the string with a blank string_ was not a typo. That code did replace the string with a blank string.

Comment: @djames: You  must use regex delimiters (one at the start, the other at the end) with `preg_` functions.